# Flutter TextFormField Hide softkeyboard and device keyboard input, but accept barcode scanner input

Tags: flutter

We are using an Android PDA device with barcode scanner for stock taking application. We want to disable all input in the textfiled include softkeybaord and device keyboard but exclude barcode scanner input. How to achieve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `readOnly` property to `true` and provide a `TextEditingController` to change the value inside the textfield:

```
TextFormField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: _controller,
  ...
),
```

And then you change the value like this:

```
_controller.text = "..."
```